# xxx.resources.dll not generated after build in en-us

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resources

xxx.resources.dll should be generated after build in en-us folder right? I use vs2012 but it's not now. And I've already added the following line in AssemblyInfo file. Please help and thanks in advance.

[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find the answer myself.
Add UICulture>en-US/UICulture> in project file